# How to select the latest x entries in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE 'myfield' = false
```

How can I select the latest x entries, for example the latest 10?

How would I need to format that in SQL?

Comment: The 10 latest inserted rows? Do you have a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column where you store the insertion_time?

Comment: ... or at least an auto-incrementing id column? Absent that or a date to order by as suggested by @ypercube, the table order is not in any way deterministic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have some field in that table which represents time of insertion/update, you can't do it. You need something like that in order to add an `ORDER BY... LIMIT 10` clause. Another option would be to have a numeric field with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` property (maybe the primary key ?).

The RDBMS is under no obligation to return the rows in a specific order (and it is wrong to rely on it), UNLESS you specify it explicitly.